# Ошибка Found non-callable @@iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вызываю обычную функцию

```
function newtym(x1, y1, rift){
        x = x1*Math.cos(koef*Math.PI/180) + y1*Math.sin(koef*Math.PI/180);
        y = y1*Math.cos(koef*Math.PI/180) - x1*Math.sin(koef*Math.PI/180);

        x = (focus['x'] + x)*scroll;
        y = (focus['y'] + y)*scroll;

        koef += 0.1;
        if (rift == 'y'){
            return y;
        }
        if (rift == 'x'){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return [x,y];
        }

    }
```

Превращаю координаты, но это неважно. Дальше вызываю - и получаю ошибку:

```
ctx.lineTo(...newtym(100, 100, ''));
```

неважно как вызываю, есть ли третий параметр. Ошибка одна и та же - Found non-callable @@iterator js

Comment: @StrangerintheQ рисует линию от курсора к точке

Comment: А кто переменные объявлять будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var koef = 0;
function newtym(x1, y1, rift) {
  x = x1 * Math.cos(koef * Math.PI / 180) + y1 * Math.sin(koef * Math.PI / 180);
  y = y1 * Math.cos(koef * Math.PI / 180) - x1 * Math.sin(koef * Math.PI / 180);

  x = (focus['x'] + x) * scroll;
  y = (focus['y'] + y) * scroll;

  koef += 0.1;
  if (rift == 'y') {
    return y;
  }
  if (rift == 'x') {
    return x;
  } else {
    return [x, y];
  }
}

var a = [...newtym(12, 34, '')];
console.log(a);
```

```js
var koef = 0;
function newtym(x1, y1, rift) {
  x = x1 * Math.cos(koef * Math.PI / 180) + y1 * Math.sin(koef * Math.PI / 180);
  y = y1 * Math.cos(koef * Math.PI / 180) - x1 * Math.sin(koef * Math.PI / 180);

  x = (focus['x'] + x) * scroll;
  y = (focus['y'] + y) * scroll;

  koef += 0.1;
  if (rift == 'y') {
    return y;
  }
  if (rift == 'x') {
    return x;
  } else {
    return [x, y];
  }
}

var a = [...newtym(12, 34, 'y')];
console.log(a);
```

Comment: во втором варианте выдает ошибку newtym(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: @shumik_UA потому что Вы возвращаете одно значение, а не массив, в первых двух `return`-ах

Comment: спасибо, заработало